# Can't load a controller's view inside of an UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have `PhotosGridController`, which only has a collectionView added as a subView of it's view. This Viewcontroller holds all the delegates and datasource of it's collectionView, so, my code gets a bit cleaner.

I also have a `MainPageController`, which has another collectionView *(the main one)*, and inside of that, it's a custom cell *(named MainPageCell)*. This cell has a UIView named `imageViewGrid`, and it's purpose is to show the PhotoGridController's view. But here's the bug: when I run my code after adding the `PhotosGridController` as a childController of the `MainPageController`, and add it's view as a `imageViewGrid` subView, **nothing loads properly on the displayed cells**. Actually, when I scroll down/up, I can see the desired collectionView for almost a second, and when I stop scrolling, **it disappears again.**

**MainPage collectionView's datasource:**

```
extension MainPageController {

. . .

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MainPageCell
    
    displayController(contentController: photoGridController, on: cell.imageViewGrid)
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    return cell
}
}
```

**MainPage displayController method:**

```
extension MainPageController {

func displayController(contentController content: UIViewController, on view: UIView) {
    self.addChild(content)
    view.addSubview(content.view)
    content.didMove(toParent: self)
    content.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    content.view.becomeFirstResponder()
}

}
```

**PhotoGrid datasource:**

```
extension PhotosGridController {

. . .

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoGridCell
    
    cell.backgroundColor = Colors.lightBlue
    cell.item = names[indexPath.item]
    
    return cell
}

. . .

}
```

I think the problem is on the cellForItemAt method on the MainPage, but I can't figure out how to solve it. If u need more code, let me know.

**NOTE:** If I make my PhotosGridController my rootViewController on SceneDelegate, it loads perfectly fine and shows the desired screen on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize the view of your content after the didMove

Example:

```
content.view.frame = view.bounds
content.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
content.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Comment: Done, and the bug remains.